# Catchable Fatal Error when logging with twitter in my symfony2 application

Tags: symfony, twitter, hwioauthbundle

i use FOSUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle in my symfony2 application.
I try to implement "sign in with twitter" and when i run my application in developpment mode i have this error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\PathUserResponse could not be
>   converted to string

here the stack trace :
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php at line 216

```
 private function onSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if (null !== $this->logger) {
            $this->logger->info(sprintf('User "%s" has been authenticated successfully', $token->getUsername()));
        }
        $this->securityContext->setToken($token);
```